# Pass a task to a task property

Tags: wpf, multithreading, task, reactiveui

So I have a task, that takes a path and opens the file.

```
private async Task OpenFileAsync(string strFilePath)
{
     doTheOpenThing.
}
```

Until now this was a void function and everything was ok, but know we need to support big files and we wanted to do the open file using other thread, in order to not block the UI Thread.

I use reactiveui in my application and I have a method that listens to tasks and runs them as they come.

```
        _sessionContext.WhenAnyValue(t => t.NotifyNewTreadTask).Where(t => t != null).Subscribe(t => DoAsyncTask(t));
```

Where

```
   private async void DoAsyncTask(Task task)
        {
            if (task != null)
            {
                await DoThreadAction(() => task);
            }

            _sessionContext.NotifyNewTreadTask = null;
        }
```

And DoThreadAction just runs the task

```
await Task.Run(async () => await action.Invoke());
```

Now my problem is on assigning **NotifyNewTreadTask**.

Whenever I do `NotifyNewTreadTask = OpenFileAsync(path);`

It just runs the OpenFileAsync task. How can pass OpenFileASync task to NotifyNewTreadTask without running it.

```
Task? NotifyNewTreadTask { get; set; } NotifyNewTreadTask is a property.
```

Comment: What was the type of `NotifyNewTreadTask`? How do you set it?

Comment: @mm8 added an edit with the information. NotifyNewTreadTask is a Task property. That is my question, how do I set it without running the task I set the property to.

Comment: So you're using ReactiveUI but not really using reactive programming.  @mm8 is right.  There are a lot of implementation details that are making this harder for you because you are trying to get around just using Observables for their intended purpose.

Comment: @RodneyLittles I am open to suggestions. I don't see where I am not using reactive programming or where should I use it more.

Comment: @CiucaS: Other suggestions than using a command or a `Func<T>`? What is your current issue after reading my answer?

Comment: @mm8 it's working, thank you. He said that i am not really using reactive programming, and I was curios what can be done better. Now I have other problem, as the image is open on other thread I can't use the Decoder object on my main thread.

Comment: @CiucaS: Please remember to accept the answer if your original issue has been solved and then ask a new question if you have another issue.

Comment: @CiucaS Your calling tasks withing `await Task.Run`.  Which would point to your new threading issue.  When you are using excessive amounts of tasks like this, your using Tasks to model Asynchronous programming instead of using Observables.  In an observable world, you could just tell your asynchronous task which threads to marshall back to.  Which would solve your problem.  I can't re-architect all your code here.  The best I can do is point out that you're using Tasks when I would most likley use an Observable for this purpose.

Comment: I get your point, I will try and see if I can fit this solution into the project. Sounds like a good solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a command to execute `OpenFileAsync` asynchronously instead of calling it in the `Subscribe` method:

```
 public class ViewModel
 {
    public ViewModel()
    {
        OpenFile = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask<string>(OpenFileAsync);
    }

    public ReactiveCommand<string, Unit> OpenFile { get; }

    private async Task OpenFileAsync(string strFilePath)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Instead of setting some property, you could the execute then task directly and await it:

```
await OpenFile.Execute("file.txt");
```

You may of course also invoke it as a result of some property being set:

```
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SomeStringProperty).InvokeCommand(OpenFile);
```

Setting a `Task` property to a `Task` to cause another `Task` to get executed seems a bit clumsy though.

Comment: I use a property to pass the task, as the place where the action is invoked ( DoThreadAction) and the task that it will invoke are not the same. In other words DoThreadAction is in ViewModel1 and Task is in ViewModel2.

Comment: Maybe you want a `Func<Task>` instead of a `Task` then? Pass the func and invoke it when you want to execute the task?